# Json array, get first value from each array key

Tags: php, arrays, json

What i'm trying to do is get the each array key and then associate the first "price" and "quantity" with each array key.
My array:

```
{
  "32557580": {
    "bids": [
      {
        "price": 2500,
        "quantity": 38265661
      },
      {
        "price": 2439,
        "quantity": 57414444
      },
      {
        "price": 2381,
        "quantity": 1092179
      },
      {
        "price": 2174,
        "quantity": 27140648
      }
    ],
    "offers": [
      {
        "price": 2564,
        "quantity": 33634591
      },
      {
        "price": 2597,
        "quantity": 27842125
      },
      {
        "price": 2632,
        "quantity": 925092
      },
      {
        "price": 2667,
        "quantity": 3565173
      },
      {
        "price": 2778,
        "quantity": 27589980
      }
    ]
  },
  "32557581": {
    "bids": [
      {
        "price": 4854,
        "quantity": 33786947
      },
      {
        "price": 4808,
        "quantity": 22881344
      },
      {
        "price": 4762,
        "quantity": 2513747
      },
      {
        "price": 4717,
        "quantity": 2650000
      },
      {
        "price": 4587,
        "quantity": 15714786
      }
    ],
    "offers": [
      {
        "price": 4950,
        "quantity": 31749492
      },
      {
        "price": 5000,
        "quantity": 3193999
      },
      {
        "price": 5051,
        "quantity": 2292463
      },
      {
        "price": 5102,
        "quantity": 34770816
      },
      {
        "price": 5128,
        "quantity": 2605693
      }
    ]
  },
  "32557582": {
    "bids": [
      {
        "price": 2532,
        "quantity": 60354703
      },
      {
        "price": 2500,
        "quantity": 113667648
      },
      {
        "price": 2439,
        "quantity": 5125100
      },
      {
        "price": 2222,
        "quantity": 120803051
      }
    ],
    "offers": [
      {
        "price": 2564,
        "quantity": 1492990
      },
      {
        "price": 2597,
        "quantity": 22121811
      },
      {
        "price": 2632,
        "quantity": 42119270
      },
      {
        "price": 2667,
        "quantity": 43680406
      },
      {
        "price": 2703,
        "quantity": 1176966
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example:

```
Id: 32557580
Price: 2500
Quantity: 38265661
Id: 32557581
Price: 4854
Quantity: 33786947
```

etc..

This is what i got so far

```
$obj = json_decode($result,true);
$all_keys = array_keys($obj);
foreach ($all_keys as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Id: '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Output from this is:

```
Id: 32557580
Id: 32557581
Id: 32557582
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, i have tried look at multiple questions and answers elswere. 
I tried adding another foreach inside the one i got but i only got the price and quantity from the first array key.

All help with getting me on the right track is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop the main array and get the first from `bids` and use that:

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    $first = reset($value['bids']);
    echo "ID: $key<br />";
    echo "Price: " . $first['price'] . "<br />";
    echo "Quantity: " . $first['quantity'] . "<br />";
}
```

Or use the index, which in this case is `0` but may not always be depending on the JSON:

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo "ID: $key<br />";
    echo "Price: " . $value['bids'][0]['price'] . "<br />";
    echo "Quantity: " . $value['bids'][0]['quantity'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Thank you. :)